# System.CalloutException: INVALID_TYPE: This type of object is not available for this organization on metadata API

Tags: metadata-api

I am working on the Metadata API to create an Apex trigger dynamically. I have used Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API from Github-  https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi.

The error is- 
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_TYPE: This type of object is not available for this organization faultcode=sf:INVALID_TYPE faultactor=

Comment: Questions about implementation issues need to include a specific description of the problem (including exact errors and stack traces, if any) and the code or metadata to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tooling API is simpler to use because it is JSON string based and so does not require loads of generated Apex code to be used. Note though that it does not quite support everything that the Metadata API does.

But the good news here is that the Tooling API *does* support trigger creation e.g.:

```
private String createTrigger(String name, String sourceCode, SObjectType type) {

    Map<String, String> body = new Map<String, String>{
        'Name' => name,
        'TableEnumOrId' => String.valueOf(type),
        'Body' => sourceCode
    };

    String url = ''
        + Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()
        + '/services/data/'
        + 'v48.0'
        + '/sobjects/'
        + 'ApexTrigger';

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(JSON.serialize(body));
    req.setEndpoint(url);

    HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);

    return String.format(
        'Result of {0} POST is statusCode={1} body={2}',
        new Object[] {url, res.getStatusCode(), res.getBody().abbreviate(1000)}
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Keith. It worked perfectly and I learned a new thing. :)

Comment: Glad it helped @SunadRasane.

Comment: But problem is you can not create trigger with Inactive status. What if we need to control the status while creating?